# Get custom HTTP Header with Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I need to get the text of a custom HTTP Header with Javascript, the header I need is not the User Agent, I already have that covered with this code:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent
```

What I need is to get the **content** (like: `Custom Header Text`) of a custom header called (for example): `CustomHeader`.

The Header is sent by the browser when accessing a website (and showing it to the user) with the Javascript code on the website, so I guess I would have no problem with the same-origin policy, since it's only a website with a Javascript code on it (with `script` tags).

Is it possible? If so, how can I get the content of that header with Javascript?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're trying to get a header that's sent by the browser, or a header that's returned by the server?

Comment: The header is sent by the browser

Comment: Where is the custom header coming from? Why can't you get it from that code?

Comment: An Android app, is sent like this: extraHeaders.put("CustomHeader", "Custom Header Text");

Comment: Unless the server sends the information back to the client, I don't think there's any way to get it on the client.

Comment: I checked with test header and I'm using Chrome inspection tools and the app is sending the header and it appears as customheader: Custom Header Text, it seems like it gets all in lowercase, since Javascript can get the user-agent header, I thought that it can also get a custom one sent by the browser as well (and at the same time)

Comment: It's not getting the User-Agent header from the current page, `navigator.userAgent` is a property of the browser that tells it what it should send when making future requests.

Comment: That's bad... thanks anyway, can you write that as an answer to accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

You can read more here: [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: He's clarified that he's asking about headers that were sent by the client, not headers that come back from the server.